# Updating source of an image in a second html due to output of a JavaScript eventlistener of the first html page

Tags: javascript, html

just to set the scene I'm figuring out web development on my own so don't have a lot of knowledge and I hope you could help me out.

So the concept is on HTML page 1 I choose a image and due to the clicking I change it in the second html page.

This is the js file linked to the first html page. Here I store my source of the chosen image in the variable result.

```
result="";

document.getElementById("choice1").addEventListener("click", function() { 
var elem =document.getElementById("choice1");
result = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("background-image");
return result
});

document.getElementById("choice2").addEventListener("click", function() { 
var elem =document.getElementById("choice2");
result  = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("background-image");
return result
});

document.getElementById("choice3").addEventListener("click", function() { 
var elem =document.getElementById("choice3");
result  = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("background-image");
return result

});
```

The second html is shown below. The source of the image (here set at nature) should be changed when I choose another image on the first html through the previous js file above

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <img id="current" src="nature.jpg" width="100%" height=auto>


    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="expose.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

The js file for the second html looks like this. I use setInterval to make it update automatically only if the current image on html2 isn't the same as the source of the id="current" image

```
setInterval(currentStatus,3000)

currentStatus{

    if(document.getElementById("current").src !== result) {

        document.getElementById("current").src = result
        console.log("changes applied")

    } else {
        console.log("nothing changed")
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help !
(ps: I prefer not to work with local storage)

Comment: I think it all depend on how you serve your html files

Comment: Well you have two choices. Remember you're trying to remember something between page loads. That means either logging it (ideally in local storage), or passing it in the URL, e.g. as a URL parameter, then having your page 2 JS parse the param from the URL.

Comment: You can also use cookies, btw.

Comment: Local storage will only work if you work with both html pages within the same device I suppose ? (not really familiar with local storage)

Comment: IMO the best way to do this is by using websockets. This way, you can litterally communicate between tabs through the server. Tab 1 would notify that the source has changed, and instantly, the information would be pushed to Tab 2. But that may still be out of reach for someone who's discovering web development

Comment: How feasible is it to save the chosen source in a txt file and overwriting it over and over again. The second html would then always check this file to compare it to the current exposed image ?